# She'll never stop being angry with me

Tags: sentence-meaning

**A**: Well. What happened? Did you recite my poem to my girlfriend?
**B**: Yes.
**A**: And then, what did she say? Did she give you a message for me?
**B**: Well...
**A**: Did she or didn't she?
**B**: Yes. She gave me a message for you.
**A**: Let me have it then.
**B**: I don't think you re going to like it.

.
.
.

**B**: I think your poem made her angry.
**A**: Oh, no. My poem made her angry? Now she'll  never forgive me.
**B**: She'll never forgive  you?
**A**: No. **She'll never stop being angry with me**.
Oh, I'm so miserable and heartbroken.

---

What does "**She'll never stop being angry with me**" mean?

Thank you

Comment: You are supposed to use the context to help understand.  Given that "My poem made her angry"  and "I'm so heartbroken".  What do you think it could mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "she'll remain angry with me forever".

Compare

> I will stop walking.  (simple affirmative)

> I won't stop walking.  (simple negative)

> I'll never stop walking (emphatic negative)

The second and third mean the same, but the third is stronger, and explicitly means that you will continue walking forever.

Comment: Thank you so much, James